# Why are my reading on my temperature probe so high?

Tags: arduino

We are trying to test the readings of a simple DS18B20 temperature probe. The readings are coming but they are all coming out to be -127.0 degrees. We are not sure where to go from here. The pin is located in Digital pin 8 because it produces better numbers and data points for the project. Can not move it to analog due to shortage of pins. Also we are using the Arduino Nano as our power house.

We have tried adding in a string temp, since that is hat is needed to complete the code, adding a float temp, but that didn't seem to work with the string temp. We have tried each of these together and both of them individually and those still do not seem to fix the problem at hand.

```
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 8             // Temperature sensor pin
#define MOSI 11                    // SD
#define MISO 12
#define SCK 13
#define CS 10

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

float temp = 0.0;
String time_str = "";
String data_str = "";
//String temp = "";
int temperature = 0;
digitalWrite(HBRIDGE, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
        delay(500);              // wait for a second
        buckVoltage = analogRead(BUCK_IN);
        hbridgeVoltage = analogRead(HBRIDGE_IN);
        negativeData = hbridgeVoltage - buckVoltage;
        Serial.println(negativeData);
        delay(500);

sensors.requestTemperatures();
        temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
        DateTime c = rtc.now();
        String seconds = "";
        if (c.second() < 10) {
          seconds = '0' + c.second();
        }
        else {
          seconds = c.second();
        }
        time_str = String(c.month()) + '/' + String(c.day()) + "/" + 
String(c.year()) + "," +
                   String(c.hour()) + ":" + String(c.minute()) + ":" + 
seconds;
        data_str = String(temp) + ',' + String(positiveData) + ',' + 
    String(negativeData);

Serial.println(time_str + ',' + data_str);
        f.println(time_str + ',' + data_str);
        f.close();
```

In theory our results should read that of the temperature of the substance we are testing, but the results are nonsensical and have no meaning behind them since it only reads a negative number every time.

Comment: You're reading 0xFF everytime which to me indicates an issue communicating with the device as 1-wire is a pull down protocol and the line is never getting pulled low. I recommend sniffing the one wire communications with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.

Comment: Thank yo for the help with! the data sheet showed us that we needed another resistor in our system. Thank you for the information and the help.